# H3 is aligning right of center, need a fresh set of eyes

Tags: html, css

I have a potentially stupid question here.

I've got a fiddle with a block of welcome text coming up off-center. I'm usually excellent at trouble-shooting my own CSS but this is making me absolutely batty. I've stripped all of the extra margin autos and text-align centers away to make this clearer. You can actually delete the entire JS segment and set the #welcome DIV opacity back to 1 for further clarity.

http://jsfiddle.net/Imperative/29Aat/88/

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#wrap {
    zoom: 1;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#welcome {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0px;
}
#welcome h3 {
    font-family:'Alegreya SC', serif;
    font-size: 42px;
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}
```

I'm clearly missing something really novice and really obvious but I'm too close to this thing 88 iterations in and I'm completely missing the boat.

What is cascading downwards from html, body, wrap and causing the whole #welcome block to shift right? I would have expected a lot of positions without any efforts at centering anything but a 50% shift to the right? What the frack?

Comment: Damn good question. I tried the code in Chrome and fiddled around with the developer tools but couldn't find out what's causing the offset.

Comment: Added the answer. As it turns out, due to the relative positions all over the place, #welcome was aligning to the right of #nav. Artur allowed me to see that when he made <nav> 100% wide and it fixed the centering below. Lightbulb on... clear the float on #welcome and bam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<nav>` element can't contain `<li>` elements. You have to put them into a `<ul>`:

```
nav
  ul
    li
    li
```

As for your *actual* problem: your `header` is collapsing because it contains floating elements. Give it `overflow: auto` and it will resize to fit them:

```
header.topbar {
    overflow: auto;
    /* Get rid of this: height: 80px; */
}
```

Finally, center the text:

```
#welcome {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And it works: http://jsfiddle.net/29Aat/103/

Comment: It would recommend giving the topbar an overflow:hidden, which is the standard for these kind of things.

Comment: @JacoKoster: As long as the child elements don't flow out of the container, it doesn't make any difference. I use `overflow: auto` because you can see the scrollbars in case they do.

Comment: And that is the exact reason why i usually don't use auto ;-)

Comment: I managed to solve it with a pretty simple modification. Cleared the float on the #welcome DIV.

Comment: Also, <li> inside of <nav> is standard in HTML5. The trick is to add in modernizr later so that LT IE9 doesn't barf.

Comment: Well, you are wrong there, it is not a standard in HTML5... see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context

Comment: @Imperative: No, `<nav>` is just a block-level element. You're probably thinking of `<menu>`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly you want the header completely in the center. But you didn't define nav width. 
Here's the updated fiddle:[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4b53B/)

Here's what I added:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
}

#welcome h3 {
    text-align: center
}
```

Comment: The header contains the NAV. I'm more concerned with the Welcome text in the center of the page. You have, however, pointed me in the right direction. The NAV width of 100% is directly affecting the center position of #welcome. I wouldn't have thought of that... let's see if I can separate those two misbehaving children.

Comment: Now that you mention it - I did not notice that initially. But I think it has something to do how relative position works relatively together with other elements.

Comment: You were going in the right direction. Relative positioning makes things get a bit... weird. Despite the DIV being outside of the Header area, it was still aligning to the right of the NAV. Ultimately, all I had to do was clear the float on #welcome and the problem went away: http://jsfiddle.net/Imperative/29Aat/102/

Answer (score 1):

Ended up being a simple solution:

```
#welcome {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0px;
    clear: both;
}
#welcome h3 {
    font-family:'Alegreya SC', serif;
    font-size: 42px;
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    text-align: center;
}
```

I had to clear the float on the Welcome, at which point positioning went back to normal. At that point, adding the center back to the H3 worked as expected.

Fixed Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Imperative/29Aat/102/

Comment: Do note that this isn't really "solving" the problem. Your `<li>` elements are still flowing out of the `<header>` (resize the browser window and you'll see what I mean).

Comment: Mmm... good point. I'll clean that up by fixing the overflow and encasing things in a proper ul.

Comment: Well that didn't go as expected. Give me a minute :p

Comment: Just go with Blender's answer. He's already done everything you need to do.

Comment: Right, overflow:hidden on the header.
http://jsfiddle.net/Imperative/29Aat/104/

Now it doesn't flow out but that is fine, since I'm going to add a responsive component up there anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML, I would first wonder if the #wrap is sitting beside the #welcome, causing it to move off center?

Okay, I'm still learning  this stackoverflow thing, so cut me a bit of slack on operations here please. That being said, I see now what this jsfiddle thing can do.

Looking at the html code, you never closed the wrap-div before opening the welcome-div.

That the problem you looking at? I tried closing the div tag and adding a text-align:center to the css, but now the welcome banner has disappeared.

---

Okay, a bit of code tinkering lead to this:

1) Close the Wrap-div tag (I'm pretty certain that I managed to put it in the right place)
2) Modify the CSS bank:

```
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
top: 25%;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
```

Comment: The #wrap DIV closes on line 41. It exists to wrap all of the page elements in a single DIV for CSS and JS targeting purposes.

Comment: Also, yes, when you are trying new things in a conceptual interface it's very useful to develop it in JSFiddle, since questions can be very quickly referenced here at stackoverflow :)

It has limitations on more complex projects but for specific plugins or positioning issues it's quite useful.